# $xy^2x^{-1}=y^3$ implies $[xyx^{-1},y]=1$

Tags: first-order-logic, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

I want to show that if $x,y$ are elements of an hyperbolic group $G$, and $xy^2x^{-1}=y^3$, then $[xyx^{-1},y]=1$.
I tried to show that by using triangle thinness but I reached nothing. Another observation is that calling $z=xyx^{-1}$, then we have that $z^2$ lays in the centraliser of $y$, also $y^3$ lays in the centraliser of $z$, and we want to show that $z$ is in the centraliser of $y$. I tried to use the fact that centralisers of elements of infinite order must be virtually cyclic in $G$ but I’m not sure that $y$ must have infinite order.

Comment: There is a more general fact saying that for any $y \in G$, the cyclic group $\left< y \right>$ that it generates has finite index in its centralizer $C(y)$. This does have, as a corollary, the fact that if $y$ has infinite order then $C(y)$ is indeed virtually cyclic. On the other hand this also tells you that if $y$ has finite order then $C(y)$ is finite. Does that help?

Comment: I'll also point out that there is a still more general theorem. Define the *virtual normalizer* $VN\left< y \right>$ (also known as the commensurator of $\left< y \right>$) to be the subgroup of all $h \in G$ such that $\left< y \right> \cap \left< h y h^{-1} \right>$ has finite index in both $\left< y \right>$ and $\left< h y h^{-1} \right>$. Note that the centralizer and the normalizer are both subgroups of the virtual normalizer. The general theorem is that $\left< y \right>$ has finite index in $VN\left< y \right>$. Your hypotheses imply that $x \in VN\left< y \right>$, so that might help.

Comment: @LeeMosher in a hyperbolic group the centralizer of an element of finite order can be infinite.

Comment: If $y$ has finite order, $y^2$ conjugate to $y^3$ implies that $y^2$ and $y^3$ have the same order, and hence have the same order, and since subgroups of the same order in a cyclic group are equal, one deduces that $y^2$ and $y^3$ generate the same subgroup. Since these have $1$ or $2$, resp $1$ or $3$ in $\langle y\rangle$, one deduces that $y,y^2,y^3$ generate the same subgroup $C$, which means that the order of $y$ is coprime to 6. This also implies that $x$ normalizes $C$, and the conclusion follows (when $y$ has finite order).

Comment: Oops, careless, you're right.